# Python Output Only 1 Column

Tags: python, yfinance

I'm using yfinance and trying to get both volume and date columns, but this code outputs other information such as price and dividends that I don't need. I need the numbers as integers so I can then make a graph using matplotlib.

```
import yfinance as yf

ES = yf.Ticker("ES=F").history(period='max')
print(ES)
```

Comment: Have you tried to use any of the methods and attributes shown here? https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance#quick-start

Comment: You don't need the numbers as integers in order to make a graph. Floating-point numbers can be plotted as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no function for volume

Comment: I thought it had to be integers, thank you for letting me know.

Comment: I still need to know how to only get 1 column of data out of a table

Comment: i don't understand what you want but to get volume - `ES["Volume"]` or `ES.Volume`

Comment: Specify only the volume column at the time of acquisition. `ES = yf.Ticker("ES=F").history(period='max')['Volume']`

Comment: Thank you @r-beginners @furas ! I will use the values as my x variable for my graph, but how can I get the dates as well? I tried using `ES = yf.Ticker("ES=F").history(period='max')['Date']` but that wouldnt work.

Comment: If you need an index, you can get it with `ES.index` since the ES just described is a data frame.

Comment: @r-beginners this is great! how can I use this to make a chart using matplotlib? I'm currently trying `plt.plot(Volume,Date)
plt.title('Equity Futures Volume')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plot.show()`

However, matplotlib isn't getting the line `plt.plot(Volume,Date)` where `plt.plot(Volume,Date)` and `Volume = (ES['Volume'])`

Comment: Try this: `plt.plot(ES.index, ES.Volume);plt.show()`

Comment: @r-beginners I'm getting `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'plot'`

Comment: Try this: `import yfinance as yf;import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;ES = yf.Ticker("ES=F").history(period='max');plt.plot(ES.index, ES.Volume);plt.show()`

Answer (score 0):

`Date` is part of the Index already. You can omit all other columns but `Volume` using `...['Volume']`.

You might want to use the following code:

```
import yfinance as yf
df = yf.Ticker("ES=F").history(period='max')['Volume']
df.plot(title="Ticker: ES=F")
```

**Output:**

[image: Volume of ES=F]